# What is the difference between validationQuery and isValid() in SpringBoot (DataSourceHealthIndicator)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, hikaricp

We use Spring Boot 2.7.x with hikaryCP, MySql. Using Actuator API to do the DB health check.
We haven't configure hikary:connection-test-query in application yaml file.

Since the DataSourceHealthIndicator is using the [JdbcTemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.7.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/jdbc/DataSourceHealthIndicator.java#L130) to execute the query, it should fetch the connection from the HikaryCP.

As per the below code, *else* condition will be executed in this case.

Below are my queries:

- How the validation happening with the isValid() method?
- What query will be executed?
- Will it create a new connection or use the existing connection
  from the pool?

[image]

Comment: IMO, what is written in `DataSourceHealthIndicator` does not make any sense: checking whether jdbc connection is valid/alive or not is a responsibility of `DataSource`, so, in case of `isValid()` branch the result is always `UP` (if DB is unavailable the exception gets thrown much earlier). Using `validationQuery` would make sense if they were recording response time.